# Tensorflow model prediction failes when ran right after model training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm having troubles with my model prediction. The training works fine  but afterwards my program fails while predicting the trained model. When I rerun my code the training is now skipped because its already done, the prediction works now fine as its supposed to. In google I find this error only with regard to model training so i guess the solutions don't work for me. I think the reason for my error is, that my video ram is not entirely freed after model training. That's why I tried the following without success.

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
K.clear_session()
```

Error code:

```
prediction = model.predict(x)[:, 0]#.flatten()  # flatten was needed now
  File "/home/max/PycharmProjects/Masterthesis/venv3-8-12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/max/PycharmProjects/Masterthesis/venv3-8-12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 106, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve the problem?

My Setup:

- Python: 3.8.12
- Tensorflow-gpu: 2.7.0
- System: Manjaro Linux
- Cuda: 11.5
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti

My Code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Dropout
import tensorflow as tf
import h5py
import keras.backend as K


def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    alpha = K.std(y_pred) / K.std(y_true)
    beta = K.sum(y_pred) / K.sum(y_true)
    error = K.sqrt( + K.square(1 - alpha) + K.square(1 - beta))

    return error


i = Input(shape=(171, 11))
x = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(i)
x = LSTM(50)(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
out = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(i, out)
model.compile(
    loss=loss_function,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))

with h5py.File("db.hdf5", 'r') as db_:
    r = model.fit(
        db_["X_train"][...],
        db_["Y_train"][...],
        epochs=1,
        batch_size=64,
        verbose=1,
        shuffle=True)
model.save("model.h5")

model = load_model("model.h5", compile=False)

with h5py.File("db.hdf5", 'r') as db:
    x = db["X_val"][...]
    y = db["Y_val"][...].flatten()
    prediction = model.predict(x)[:, 0].flatten()
```

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of your code so we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Yes sure I can try that.

Comment: Are you trying to use a GPU because I don't find the  where you assigne them.
A possible quick fix/try could be reducing the batch size in your fit to a smaller size. To check you could try with a barchsize of 2 or 4.

Comment: I'm using the tensorflow GPU package, with that I don't need to specify whether I want to use the GPU or not. I don't want to reduce the batch size, cause the training works with the assigned batch size or are they not the same?

Comment: I mistyped use the batch_size in predict: `predict(
    x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False
)`
So as example `prediction = model.predict(x, batch_size=4)[:, 0].flatten()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the batch size wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Since I'm using a custom loss function, I somehow needed to specify the custom loss function when loading the model again.
I accomplished this by modifying this line

`model = load_model("model.h5", compile=False)`

to this one

`model = load_model("model.h5", custom_objects={"loss_function": loss_function})`